# Cannot display the background image

Tags: html, css

I've tried to display the background image but didn't succeed to do it.
I don't know what is the problem with my code.

```css
 .comparison .product {
  background-image: url('/static/img/neotic_payment.png') no-repeat 95% center;
  background: #3d5c5c;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="comparison">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="product"></th>
        <th class="product">Starter</th>
        <th class="product">Standard</th>
        <th class="product">Super</th>
        <th class="product" style="-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #4eba7b;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #4eba7b;
        -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #4eba7b;
        -o-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #4eba7b;
        box-shadow: 0 0 25px #4eba7b;  z-index: 100;">Ultimate</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: just remove second ;) from center and move center next to 95% with space =  background-image: url('/static/img/neotic_payment.png') no-repeat 95% center;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned background-image, background tag at same time. Your background color is working and image not. Try this one to show color with image:

```
background: url('image-path') no-repeat 95% #3d5c5c;
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bw87abgL/)

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your css. The background-image has no semicolon after "95%", and "center" has 2 semicolons.

```
 .comparison .product {
background-image: url('/static/img/neotic_payment.png') no-repeat 95%; 
background: #3d5c5c;
height: 40px;
font-size: 1.6em;
background-image: contain;
}
```

Comment: what is center?

Comment: @SagarKodte Center is invalid CSS and shouldn't be in there. I removed it from my anwser accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `css` to that `css`

```
.comparison .product {
    background-image: url('/static/img/neotic_payment.png');
    background: #3d5c5c;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
 }
```